# (App Name).build.appxrecipe" does not exist .net maui TargetFrameWork Change

Tags: .net, maui

The App wont start on windows showing the error "(App Name).build.appxrecipe" does not exist. You may need to build your project"
It Happened Because I Changed The Target FrameWork from .net6 to .net7

i Tried Rebuilding The Project And Deploying it but I Get The Error "Error The recipe file bin\Debug\net6.0\ExamApp.App.build.appxrecipe" does not exist. You may need to build your project.
i even tried going back to .net6 and the problem is still Existing.
Many Thanks In Advance.

Comment: You can try to delete bin and obj folders, then restart your visual studio and try again.

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT Thanks for the comment but it didnt work unfortunately also i havent saved a copy on github so its looks like ill create a new project and just copy the files

Comment: Coping code from previous app is also a common way to troubleshoot problems. Hope your problem can be solved.